# R: Identical SE values for all slopes in an lm

Tags: r, stderr, lm

I'm relatively new to R, and I just encountered a problem that I haven't before.  I ran an lm with species richness as the response variable and elevation level (I have five of them ranging from 3000 m to 5000 m; it's a categorical variable) as the predictor.  The model output gives me the exact same values for standard errors for all the slopes (0.7709 for the intercept, and 1.0903 for the other 4 elevations).  The data seems to be all right... I'm not able to put my finger on what might be the problem.  Have any of you encountered a similar problem? I would greatly appreciate suggestions on where I should look for potential issues.

Comment: Why are you assuming this is a problem?

Comment: Well, I get different values for the SEs for each elevation if I just calculate it directly from the data.  Besides, I just thought it was odd that the SEs were the same to four decimal places...

Comment: Can't really tell us if you're doing something wrong unless we see a reproducible example of your code

Comment: I'm voting to migrate to Cross Validated because this is a question about statistical understanding, not R.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to produce data that have that property. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(1e3)
x <- rep(1:4, length.out = 1e3)
y <- y + x
summary(lm(y ~ factor(x)))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ factor(x))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.0078 -0.6817 -0.0251  0.6980  3.8188 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.95308    0.06554   14.54   <2e-16 ***
factor(x)2   1.04662    0.09269   11.29   <2e-16 ***
factor(x)3   2.03841    0.09269   21.99   <2e-16 ***
factor(x)4   3.05606    0.09269   32.97   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.036 on 996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5468,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5454 
F-statistic: 400.6 on 3 and 996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Probably, there's nothing per se wrong with your code or necessarily your data. This is probably actually a statistical question, not an R question.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll probably ask in a stats forum then, to understand better when SEs could behave this way.